# Accessing Variable values from another file c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am doing something that requires a password.

right now I am able to create files and store custom user input in that but I cant seem to find anywhere how to store a variable with the user created value, and make it so that the next time the program starts it will be able to read that file and understand the value.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
string user;
string pass;
string entry;

std::ifstream f("test.txt");
if (f.fail()) {
    std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");

    cout << "Please make a username.\n";
    cin >> user;

    cout << "Please make a password.\n";
    cin >> pass;

    outfile << user << std::endl;
    outfile << pass << std::endl;

    outfile.close();

    cout << "Please restart.\n";
    int x = 3000;
    Sleep(x);
}

else {
    cout << "please enter username\n";
    cin >> entry;

    if (entry == user) {
        cout << "Welcome";
        int x = 3000;
        Sleep(x);
    }

    else if (entry != user) {
        cout << "Nope";
        int x = 3000;
        Sleep(x);
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the necessary code to read the saved user name and password. In the `else` part of the function, add

```
f >> user;
f >> pass;
```

as the first two lines.

```
else {

    // Read the user name and password from the file.
    f >> user;
    f >> pass;

    cout << "please enter username\n";
    cin >> entry;

    if (entry == user) {
        cout << "Welcome";
        int x = 3000;
        Sleep(x);
    }

    else if (entry != user) {
        cout << "Nope";
        int x = 3000;
        Sleep(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string::find` function to search your string in a file after `ifstream`.

```
if (string1.find(string2) != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "found\n";
}
else
{
 std::cout << "not found\n";
}
```